# PHP - Access Code Form Submission not working?

Tags: php

I have PHP code  that is supposed to have a access code in the PHP code. When you go to the page you enter the access code and if correct it continues to another page, if not it gives a error message.

**HERE IS MY CODE:**

```
<?php
  $code = $_POST[$code];
  $code = '7613';

  if($code == '7613') {
      echo " it worked! ";
  } else {
      echo "it did not work !";
  }

  ?>


  <form action="login.php" method="post">
      <input type="password" name="code" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

  </form>
```

Comment: This will never work. You overwrite `$code` right after you take it from `$_POST`, assuming you are getting the value back. Correction: it will work every time, but not the way you intend it do.

Comment: I do not understand can you show me?

Comment: What's your question? Why do you have the line `$code = '7613';`?

Comment: Nevermind, there are so many errors. You cannot use `$code` as an index before it is even set in the script. Also, you then rewrite the value for `$code` on the next line.

Comment: @j08691 I have a access code in my code that when i enter a code on my web-page it will redirect me to another page, if not it returns a error.

Comment: Please take the time to learn some basic PHP fundamentals before writing any more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it

**CODE:**

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $code = $_POST['code'];

if($code == '7613') {
    echo " it worked! ";
} else {
    echo "it did not work !";
   }
}

?>

<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="password" name="code"  maxlength="4" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

The two variables are different for starters. They can be matched. Look into the isset function and empty function. I check to see if the value exists, if it does, I validate it. If not, just show the form and dont try to validate nothing.

```
    <?php
$code = isset( $_POST['code'] ) ? $_POST['code'] : NULL;
$codeToMatch = '7613';

if ( ! empty( $code ) )
{
    if( $code == $codeToMatch ) {
        echo "it worked!";
    } else {
        echo "it did not work !";
    }
}


?>


<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="password" name="code" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```